# Correct way to use Enums in Groovy and Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, enums

I want to create a number of global enums that are for use throughout my entire application.

I created a groovy file called enums which looks something like this:

```
class Enums {
    enum GameType{
        Game1,
        Game2,
        Game3
        Game4
        Game5
    }

    enum Enum2{
        Type1,
        Type2,
        Type3
    }

}
```

The first enum seems to work fine, but when I try to use the second one I get an 'unable to resolve class' error. What is the correct way to work with Enums in Grails?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Each enumeration should be in it's own class located under in `src/groovy`. I would also suggest using a package for them. Your example should be

`src/groovy/my/example/GameType.groovy`:

```
package my.example
enum GameType{
  Game1,
  Game2,
  Game3,
  Game4,
  Game5
}
```

`src/groovy/my/example/Enum2.groovy`:

```
package my.example
enum Enum2 {
  Type1,
  Type2,
  Type3
}
```

Comment: You mean `/src/groovy` not `grails-app/src/groovy` right?

Comment: Indeed I did. Fixed that. Thanks for the spot check. Guess my brain checked out for a bit.

Comment: In Grails, I tend to use Enums as properties within services; say, if I have an enduring business need to use `enum foobar { FOO, BAR }` on methods explicitly within FooBarService.   However, that is assuming I _only_ want to use that enum within that service (or it is used elsewhere but relates to some common theme of that service - e.g. I'm performing some kind of action with a related `Foo` and `Bar` domain Class within a different service).  I haven't really found much use for enum beyond that within Grails. Ergo, this is in addendum to the above rather than an answer in itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the enums in one file; perhaps Enums.groovy.

```
package com.myapp

enum GameType{
    Game1,
    Game2,
    Game3,
    Game4,
    Game5
}

enum Enum2{
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3
}
```